# How to debug methods called by JUnit in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

If I write a test class such as:

```
public class TryOut {

    public int doStuff()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        int five = 5;
        return five * 2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TryOut myTryOut = new TryOut();
        myTryOut.doStuff();
    }
}
```

and use JUnit to test it

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TryOutTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        TryOut myTryOut = new TryOut();
        int answer = myTryOut.doStuff();
        assertEquals(10, answer);
    }

}
```

What I want is to step through the code when JUnit is running.  Is this possible?  If I set a breakpoint on the method that gets called - doStuff()
and then right click on the TryOutTest class, then Debug As, JUnit test menu options, (to run the code) the breakpoint never stops the code, and the test completes.

Comment: That should work out of the box. Try putting the breakpoint on the line before within your test.

Comment: Of course debug should work for you.  Check that your breakpoint is not disabled and option disabling all breakpoints is not enabled as well

Comment: why did you debug in unit-tests? maybe you need make the test smaller into a couple of tests, see the section [Test Isolation](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TestIsolation) section would be helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your breakpoint is not skipped (in case you see a `backslash` on the breakpoint, it is skipped).
In case it is skipped, press `Ctrl+Alt+B` to enable it.